# jquery draggable custom containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jsfiddle

I want keep object inside parent while dragging.
Sample fiddle is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy94c/4/)

```
$("#child").draggable({cursor:'move',axis: "x"});
```

axis is working fine but also child left and right should keep in parent.
You should only drag in y axis and parent width.

Thanks

Comment: Does `containment: '#parent'` not work for you?

Comment: no :( because, if child is bigger then parent, dragging will not start.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `containment` option on the draggable element. Example Code :

```
$("#child").draggable({
    cursor:'move',
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent"
});
```

Alternatively you can set this to be the ID of an element (i.e. `containment:'#parent'`)

There was a problem with your child element being constrained in your JSFiddle because it was bigger than the Parent Element. In my example fiddle below I have made the child element `width:200px;` so that it fits within the parent div (so it is constrained correctly).

<kbd>[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQZ8c/1/)</kbd>

Comment: if child is smaller than parent, your sample just works. but i need child's width or height bigger than parent's. parent will work like crop.

Comment: @RamazanBOSTAN I think you might be slightly confused about what containment is. You cannot contain an element that is bigger than the container. What exactly are you trying to achieve by this and why wouldn't your original solution work? In your original solution you can move the item around and it does not leave the parent container (i.e. moved outside it) so what do you want to do differently?

Comment: Sorry, 'containment' in first fiddle is wrong. i have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Xy94c/4/ 

Without a containment,i want to disallow #child when it is offset left same with parent offset left.

Comment: @RamazanBOSTAN I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve. Based on your fiddle you are trying to keep the child div left-aligned but allow it to be dragged along the x-axis. Is this a correct assumption? If so I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I want to disallow #child's sides (left and right in sample) to enter #parent's inside.

Comment: I have figured out it!
http://jsfiddle.net/Xy94c/6/

Html part:

    <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <span style="float:left">left</span>
        <span style="float:right">right</span>
    </div>
</div>

Js Part : 

    $("#child").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    axis: "x",
    drag:function(e,ui){
        if(ui.offset.left>$("#parent").offset().left)
            return false;
        if(ui.offset.left+ui.helper.width()<=$("#parent").offset().left+$("#parent").width())
            return false;
    }});

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: @RamazanBOSTAN If you found your answer, could you please Answer your own question? It may help future users to find a similar solution. :)

Comment: I am a newbie user and can not answer my questions :( You may check http://jsfiddle.net/Xy94c/6/